Swagger-go response model
I've a golang REST API program, with go-swagger docs as commend.
When I server the swagger.yaml there is no type to product but as array[any]
go.docs:
// A list of products
// swagger:response productsResponse
type productsResponseWrapper struct {
    // All current products EXAMPLE
    // in: body

    // Required: true
    // Example: Expected type int
    Body []data.Product
}

get.go
// swagger:route GET /products products listProducts
// Return a list of products from the database
// responses:
//   200: productsResponse

// ListAll handles GET requests and returns all current products
func (p *Products) GetProducts(rw http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    p.l.Println("Get Product")
    lp := data.GetProducts()
    if err := lp.ToJson(rw); err != nil {
        http.Error(rw, "Unable to marshal json", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

However the swagger.yaml, response model look as followed:
    productsResponse:
        description: A list of products
        headers:
            Body:
                description: 'Required: true'
                example: Expected type int
                items: {}
                type: array

EDIT:
data/product.go
// Product defines the structure for an API product
// swagger:model Product
type Product struct {
    // the id of the user
    //
    // required: true
    // min: 1
    ID          int     `json:"id"`
    Name        string  `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Description string  `json:"description"`
    Price       float32 `json:"price" validate:"gt=0"`
    SKU         string  `json:"sku" validate:"required,sku"`
    CreatedOn   string  `json:"-"`
    UpdatedOn   string  `json:"-"`
    DeletedOn   string  `json:"-"`
}

